# Insert data into html table provided in web application using selenium web driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am working on selenium webdriver and i want to insert data into the tables which are provided on web site, i have used sendkeys method but its not working for me. is there any other way to insert data into tables ?

Comment: What you have tried so far? please share html section of that table and your selenium webdriver code which you are using to send keys.

Comment: Please provide the HTML code of the table and the selenium code that you've written.

Comment: Get into first cell of table by selenium then use robot keyboard class to switch between cells by Pressing TAB button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before clicking to the cell it was having class attribute value emplty after clicking it switches from empty to current.
So now i am clicking every cell and then inserting value within it.
It is working like this now.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting data using selenium the only way to use is sendkeys() method. If I understand correct, your html table will be like below:

```
<html>
 <body>

   <table style="width:100%">
     <tr>
       <th>Firstname</th>
       <th>Lastname</th>        
       <th>Points</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
         <input></input>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input></input>
      </td>     
      <td>
         <input></input>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Get the xpath of the input table row of nth column, and use sendkeys() method

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/input")).sendKeys("Alice");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys("Smith");
```

which works for me as code written above. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Yes it is same as you said but it has class attribute for every cell, initially class value is blank when i click on a cell it changes from blank to current. So now problem is solved, i am clicking next cell which should accept next value and inserting data. Now its working....  Thank you for response.